Firebase Dynamic Links is going to deprecate in 2025, So how can we create sharable link for our future projects?

Deprecated: Firebase Dynamic Links is deprecated and should not be adopted in projects that don't already use it. The service will shut down on August 25, 2025. See the Dynamic Links Deprecation FAQ for more information.

Firebase sharable link for cross platform is going to shut down on 25 Aug, 2025.
So if i want any inner sharable link for my in-app page in flutter or android or web. how can i generate or which alternative i can use there?
